# PHP / Laravel - Tesseract OCR - Full path to file

Tags: php, laravel, tesseract

I have successfully installed tesseract OCR and Imagick on my Forge server. However when I try to read an image, I get below error:

This is the error:

```
Error! The image "/home/forge/domain.com/storage/app/temp_files/ocrtotext_ijP1II9th2.jpeg" was not found.

The current __DIR__ is /home/forge/domain.com/vendor/thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr/src
```

This is my code:

```
 $text = (new TesseractOCR(storage_path() . '/app/temp_files/'.$imageName.'.jpeg'))
        ->lang('eng')
        ->psm($psm)
        ->run();


        return $text;
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is tesseract looking in the `/vendor/` folder and not in my `storage/..` folder?

Comment: "Why is tesseract looking in the /vendor/ folder" It's not. You're misreading that error message. It's looking for `/home/forge/domain.com/storage/app/temp_files/ocrtotext_ijP1II9th2.jpeg` and can't find it. The "the current dir is" bit is just telling you where the *code* that was looking for that file is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the code at https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php/blob/ea31d13143683c1b76e622f2b76be4c3e2e6c1af/src/FriendlyErrors.php

You'll see:

```
public static function checkImagePath($image)
{
    if (file_exists($image)) return;
    $currentDir = __DIR__;
    $msg = array();
    $msg[] = "Error! The image \"$image\" was not found.";
    $msg[] = '';
    $msg[] = "The current __DIR__ is $currentDir";
    $msg = join(PHP_EOL, $msg);
    throw new ImageNotFoundException($msg);
}
```

As you can see, TesseractOCR use the function [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

This function is returning false, which means that you setted the wrong filepath, or it's a broken symlink, or the user (Apache?) doesn't have access to the file, or other reason.

Comment: can we use a image which is at S3 for this. Like generating a temp URL and passing it as the image ? . I know based on above function we cant do it. Just asking is there is any other way

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I'm not an expert in this tool but you can always download from S3 locally then set the path to TesseractOCR. It will do the same either way so you can do it by yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Just spent couple of hours with this and can only be processed with local file. We cant point external resource to it. So im just coping image from s3 to public/tmp folder. Then pass that path into to tesseract. However thanks for the reply again.Thanks to your answer I was able to rectify the issue easily.